# App is crashing on Android 12 Samsung phones

Tags: android, react-native, crash, expo, android-12

My production app is crashing on Samsung devices only on android 12.
Using rn 0.64.3 / expo bare workflow.
[Sentry Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkAK9.png)

Comment: Any luck finding the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not still have the same problem with android 12 and Samsung phones.

Comment: @Radjapa Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I still have the same problem.

Comment: After activating hermes for two weeks I haven't seen the error more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activating hermes for more than three weeks I haven't seen the error more.